# ajax - leave page while processing

Tags: ajax

What happens if a user leaves the page while its processing via Ajax?  Will the processing continue?  I use Ajax to display a loading image while it executes a script that could take a long time and am worried if users leave the page, the processing of this script will stop.  I want it to contiue whether or not the user is on the page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if the query is sent to the processing asp/php file and ajax is only waiting for the response, the query is successful.

But I think, you must add a control, like and alert asking if you would like to stay on this page or leave.

What I mean is, try writing a comment or an answer on this page and try to press the back button, an alert will appear.

With this method, you make sure the user doesn't leave before the query is complete.

Comment: ok, so are you saying the script will stop running if they leave? I can add these measures as you suggest but in some cases the queries may take up to half hour or so and people will inevitably leave. If this is the case and the processing will stop when they leave, I have to think of another way of doing this instead of using Ajax.

Comment: yes it is my guess actually, you must try it with a live demo. I think that the xmlhttprequest will be interrupted if the user quits.